# Xamarin Android XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore task could not be loaded from Xamarin.Build.Download

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

After upgrading all of my Xamarin Android nuget packages to the latest versions, I am now getting the following build error:

> /Users/justintoth/.nuget/packages/xamarin.build.download/0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(116,3):
>   error MSB4062: The
>   "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore" task could not
>   be loaded from the assembly
>   /Users/justintoth/.nuget/packages/xamarin.build.download/0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.dll.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

I've seen other references to this error and those devs were able to clean the solution, quit and restart Visual Studio for Mac, or reboot their computer. However, I've tried all three of those, manually deleting the bin / object folders, and even reinstalling Visual Studio for Mac and still am hitting this build error.

Comment: maybe try clearing the nuget cache for that package? Run this in Terminal: `rm -rf /Users/justintoth/.nuget/packages/xamarin.build.download`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I manually installed the latest Xamarin.Build nuget package and now it works. Not sure why it wasn't required before and now it is, but glad it was an easy fix...

Comment: It helped me. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This helped me too.